# Magento2: extra fee COD

Tags: magento2

I want to ask how to customize and add extra cost to customer basket for select payment "cash on delivery:".

I created file in vendor/magento-offline-payments/adminhtml/system.xml with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="cashondelivery">
                <field id="extra_fee" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="65" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Extra Fee Charge</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

In this field I add extra amount:https://prnt.sc/rqy3dr

How can I add this amount to the basket if the customer chooses this option when ordering?

Comment: You can try this extension: https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_payment_fee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this small [extension](https://github.com/bragento/magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee) which is work for you.

Hope it will help.

Happy Coding.

Comment: That's great. I was looking for that!

Comment: @Sylvester Happy Coding :)